# Jenkins - only run a job on a node with 2+ executors free

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a number of multi-jobs that run a parent job and multiple sub-jobs. The parent does some preprocessing, then kicks off the first sub-job.
Example:

- Parent - checks out git repos and preps the code

  - Build the code
  - Unit Tests
  - Upload to HockeyApp

Since the parent is running the entire time the sub-jobs are running, the process starts out with one executor, then picks up a second whenever a sub-job starts. drops it and then picks it back up when the next starts.

We have 4 nodes with 3 - 4 executors on each of them. We also don't have a networked drive so the sub job has to stay on the same executor as the parent to avoid having to pass the entire workspace between jobs.

The problem is that if one job is running and has two executors, then another gets kicked off and then another right after that, there's a chance they'll all end up on the same node and something like below happens:

Node 1

- Executor 1 - Parent1
- Executor 2 - Child1
- Executor 3 - Parent2
- Executor 4 - Parent3

Now Parent2 and Parent3 just sit around waiting for a free executor. Eventually the Child job on Parent1 ends, then 2 r 3 grabs the executor and all of them are fighting for it.

Is there a way to tell Jenkins only kick off that parent on a node with at least 2 executors free? I know if someone started enough jobs quickly enough we could still end up with man issue, but it would significantly reduce the chance of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Heavy+Job+Plugin , and define for each step the amount of free executers you need.

Comment: Awesome ty, I'll test that out!

Comment: It saves the executor, but then doesn't assign the sub-job to it, it still needs another free one to assign the sub-job to so it doesn't solve my problem. I need something similar, but that takes multi-job functionality into account. Thanks you though, I appreciate the effort!

Comment: to you want to run only 1 Parent job  at the same time ?  or you can set the weight of the parent as 3 executers...

Comment: I want to kick off a parent job on a node that has at least 2 executors free so that when the parent kicks off the child job, it's guaranteed to have an executor available on that node on which to run the child. Setting the weight doesn't help me because while it reserves the executors, it then doesn't run the child job on it so it defeats the purpose